# How to outreg multiple tables on the same document in stata?

Tags: loops, stata

How can I get `outreg` results in separate tables on the same document while I have the outreg in a loop.

I provided the answer I found below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to install `outreg` from http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/o
    ***'OUTREG': module to write estimation tables to a Word or TeX file***
(note that you need to uninstall any previous updates of outreg if found)

The documentation of the above is found [here](http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/o/outreg_complete.html). It provides examples on the following:

1. Placing additional tables in same document using `addtable`
2. Merging multiple estimation results in a loop in which you loop over `outreg` without outputting the results then `replay` over the outreg results saved in memory to output the table. Example:

   ```
   outreg, clear
   forvalues r = 2/5 {
      quietly reg mpg price weight if rep78==`r'
      outreg, merge varlabels ctitle("", "`r'") nodisplay
   }
   outreg using auto, replay replace title(Regressions by Repair Record)
   ```
3. Merging the estimation results in a loop into two separate outreg tables:  declare different tables to save in at first, then use `addtable` after the loops to output two seperate tables into word. Example:

   ```
   outreg, clear(iv)
   outreg, clear(first)
   forvalues r = 1/4 {
      quietly ivreg2 rent pcturban (hsngval = faminc) if reg`r', savefirst
      outreg, merge(iv) varlabels ctitle("","Region `r'") nodisplay
      quietly estimates restore _ivreg2_hsngval
      outreg, merge(first) varlabels ctitle("","Region `r'") nodisplay
   }
   outreg using iv, replay(first) replace title(First Stage Regressions)
   outreg using iv, replay(iv) addtable title(Variables Regression)
   ```